# Inline formset causing error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_ajax'

Tags: python, ajax, django, bootstrap-modal, inline-formset

I am using [bootstrap-modal-forms](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/) to show a user a formset with some inline forms.  It is possible for the user to save the form if data is only entered into the original form, but if the inline formset has data then I get the following error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_ajax'
```

The inline formset was working correctly before I tried to implement them in the modal form.  The problem seems to arise only when the inline formset (projectimages) is saved it is a NoneType.

My views.py

```py
class ProjectCreate(BSModalCreateView):
    form_class = ProjectForm
    template_name = 'project_form.html'
    success_message = 'Success: %(project_name)s was created.'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('project-detail', kwargs={'project': self.object.slug})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ProjectCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['projectimages'] = ProjectFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES,)
        else:
            data['projectimages'] = ProjectFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.date_created = timezone.now()
        context = self.get_context_data()
        projectimages = context['projectimages']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if projectimages.is_valid():
                projectimages.instance = self.object
                projectimages.save()

        return super(ProjectCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

My forms.py

```py
class ProjectForm(BSModalForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = ['date_created', 'slug']

ProjectFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Project,
    ProjectImage,
    can_delete=True,
    form=ProjectForm,
    extra=1,
)
```

My models.py

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('Created on')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(str(self))
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project-list')

class ProjectImage(models.Model):
    image =  models.ImageField(verbose_name='Additional Images', upload_to=project_directory_path)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    annotation = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

I expect the user to be able to add as many images to the modal formset as they like.

Comment: can you show the entire error trace?

Comment: note it's not clear to me why you use the `ProjectForm` for the inline formset, which is for a `ProjectImage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BSModalForm` expects you to initialise it with the `request`. This happens in your `BSModalCreateView` for the main form but not for your formset, because you initialise it manually.

So when initialising, just add the `form_kwargs` attribute:

```
 if self.request.POST:
     data['projectimages'] = ProjectFormSet(
         self.request.POST, self.request.FILES,
         form_kwargs={'request': self.request})
 else:
     data['projectimages'] = ProjectFormSet(form_kwargs={'request': self.request})
```

Note that I think the `form` you set in `ProjectFormSet` is wrong, because it should be a form for a `ProjectImage` model, not a `Project`. It should actually be called `ProjectImageFormSet` to better reflect what it is.

You probably want to remove `form=ProjectForm` as it probably doesn't need to be a `BSModalForm` (not sure about that). In that case you should not pass the `request` in `form_kwargs`. If not, you just need to create another `ProjectImageForm` class.

Finally, you should not `return super().form_valid()` because that will save the main form a second time (you already did). Do the redirect yourself.